# How do I php-serialize & base64_encode in PowerShell?

Tags: php, powershell, whmcs

I am trying to update a custom field in an application via the applications API.
The documentation states I need to serialize and then encode a response giving the PHP example of:

```
'customfields' => base64_encode(serialize(array("1"=>"Yahoo")));,
```

However, I am working in PowerShell.  I think the below will work for the encoding part of this, but I'm not sure how I would serialize the array first.

```
$Encodeddata = [Convert]::ToBase64String($data)
```

*The full documentation of this API is here:

https://developers.whmcs.com/api-reference/updateclientproduct/*

So far the solution for this I have looks like this :

```
$data = @{}
$data.add("1","Frank")
$sData =  ConvertTo-JSON $data
$Encodeddata =[Convert]::ToBase64String($sdata)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Cannot convert argument "inArray", with value: "{
"1":  "Frank"
```

Which suggests to me that the result of converting to Json is still an array. Im not sure how to get past that.

Comment: What is the serialized format? XML? JSON?

Comment: I'm not sure, the documentation says "Base64 encoded serialized array of custom field values - base64_encode(serialize(array(“1”=>“Yahoo”)));". I have tried  ConvertTo-xml and  ConvertTo-JSON but the encode command throws an error with both of them. It could be that the encode hit is not right.

Comment: According to [the php docs](https://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/serialize.php), it uses some kind of custom JSON-variant with type information.

Comment: I think ConvertTo-Json would work. The issue now is with encoding the result

Comment: The issue is your serialization.  The API doesn't appear to take JSON, but whatever the result of php's `serialize` method generates.